# Get selected value of ul that acts like select tag through $_POST[' '] in php script

Tags: php, jquery, select, get

I have an unordered list that acts like select tag (i decided to use it because I wanted to style it better) >>>

```
<form method='get' action="video.php">
  <div class="search-box">
    <section class="main">
      <div class="wrapper-demo">
        <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
          <span name='level' class="span-level">Level</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="get"><a href="#"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>All</a></li>
            <li class="get"><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>A1</a></li>
            <li class="get"><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>A2</a></li>
            <li class="get"><a href="#"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>B1</a></li>
            <li class="get"><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>B2</a></li>
            <li class="get"><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>C1</a></li>
            <li class="get"><a href="#"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>C2</a></li>
            <li class="get"><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large">  </i>Native</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ​</div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <button type='submit' name='search_submit'>
    <img name='search' src="img/videos.png" alt='search' class='search videos'/></button>
</form>
</form>
```

As you can see, there is:

```
<span name='level' class="span-level">Level</span>
```

But when I try to get value with:

```
$level = $_GET['level'];
```

It doesn't work.

I want to get the value of chosen value and pass it to my video.php script through:

```
if(isset($_GET['search_submit'])){
  $level = $_GET['level'];
}
```

And here is the script that puts everything together, so that `ul` will act like select tag:

```
function DropDown(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
  this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
  this.val = '';
  this.index = -1;
  this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents : function() {
    var obj = this;
    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      return false;
    });
    obj.opts.on('click',function(){
      var opt = $(this);
      obj.val = opt.text();
      obj.index = opt.index();
      obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
    });
  },
  getValue : function() {
    return this.val;
  },
  getIndex : function() {
    return this.index;
  }
}
$(function() {
  var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

I use the plugin and I guess in the jQuery script I can get somehow the value of chosen element, but I don't know how.

Anyone knows how can I make that? (how can I get the selected element and use it in my php script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *form element* with the name `level` in your HTML.  So no value with the key `level` would be sent to the server.

You'd need a form element of some kind, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="level" />
```

Then in your JavaScript where you process the click event of the "options" you'd set that value.  It looks like you get that value in your code here:

```
obj.val
```

So once you have it, you can set it in the `input`:

```
$('input[name=level]').val(obj.val);
```

That input would be what posts the value to the server, to be found in `$_GET['level']`.

Comment: obj.opts.on('click',function(){
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
          });

Comment: here - thats where u say i should put $('input[name=level]').val(obj.val); . can you tell me where exactely? im really bad with jquery

Comment: @DonaldaDonalda: Generally you'd use a value any time after you have that value.  Did you try?